# Find the number of ordered pairs (A,B) such that A∩B≠∅

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of *ordered pairs* $(A,B)$ such that $A\subseteq S$ ($A$ is a *subset* of $S$), $B\subseteq S$, and $A\cap B\ne \emptyset$ (A,B≠∅).

Im sory in advance for my poor english and luck of mathematics signuters.

**My answer is (Currect after some fixes):  $4^{n}-3^n$**

For every pair $(A,B)$ that $A,B \neq \emptyset$ , $B \in \mathscr{P}(S\setminus A) \cup (\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus \emptyset)$.
To count how many $B$ there are, I multiply:

1. All possible subgroups of A = 2^m -1 (|A|=m) that are not empty.
2. All possible subgroups of S\A = 2^(n-m)   (It is important to save the empty set so with that we get : $(A,X \in A)$ as pairs!!)

So we get a total of $(2^m -1)\cdot(2^{n-m})$ subgroups of $S$ that are not foreign to $A$.

For every group that has $m$ elements, there exist ${n \choose m}$ subgroups.

So we get:

$\Sigma_{m=1}^n {n \choose m}\cdot(2^m)\cdot(2^{n-m} -1)$ which equals $4^n - 3^n$.

Thank you,

Stav.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to find the number of *ordered pairs* $(A,B)$ such that $A\subseteq S$ ($A$ is a *subset* of $S$), $B\subseteq S$, and $A\cap B\ne \emptyset$.

First we count the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ of subsets of $S$. There are $2^n$ choices for $A$, and for each such choice there are $2^n$ choices for $B$, for a total of $2^{2n}$, that is, $4^n$.

Now we count the **bad** ordered pairs, the ones where $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

To make such an ordered pair, for every $k\le n$ we have $3$ choices for what to do with $k$: (i) $k\in A$ and $k\not\in B$; (ii) $k\in B$ and $k\not\in A$; (iii) $k$ in neither $A$ nor $B$. So there are $3^n$ bad ordered pairs.

It follows that the required number of ordered pairs is $4^{n}-3^n$.

*Remark*: Your procedure is either correct or nearly correct. You also went after the "bad" pairs. Using the binomial theorem on your sum should give us $3^n$, or something close to that.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your solution. Secondly- about that k, is it correct to say that: (i) k∈A and k∈!B; (ii) k∈B and k∈!A; (iii) k in neither A nor B ?

Comment: Yes, I should have put it that way, but because I was looking only at the bads, it is automatic that if $k\in A$ then $k\not\in B$, But still, it would be better to be explicit. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you agian. Anyway, I think my solution count how much pairs are foreign insted of not foreign to each other.

Comment: Yes, I said in a comment that you also went after the bads (disjoints). But after you count those, it is easy to get the "not disjoints." I think the number of bads is actually $\sum_0^n \binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}$, which simplifies to $3^n$.

Comment: If you could give another look on my updated solution, it would be great.

Comment: I do not understand why the subtraction of $1$ in $2^m-1$, also $2^{n-m}-1$. The non-empty will take care of itself. Also, sums should start at $0$.

Comment: For every A ∈S, B can be any combination of non empty subsets of A with non empty subsets of S\A. There are 2^m -1 non empty subsets of A and 2^(n-m) non empty subsets of S\A.

Comment: It is much cleaner to separate into two problems, number without restriction, and number that do not satisfy the restriction. However, your sum looks correct.

Comment: OK i got it: It is ok to have an empty subset of S\A becouse then I get all original subsets of A. Then i get all the missing pairs that i didnt countL (A,P(A)\emptyGroup). now i get 4^n - 3^n. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @AndréNicolas : I don't understand how did you get $3^n$ bad choices from your argument of $k$. Though I could understand the $ \sum_0^n \binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}$ argument.

Comment: We are constructing two sets $A$ and $B$ which are disjoint. So we are partitioning $S$ into $3$ parts, some of which may be empty, namely $A, B, C$, where $C$ is the complement of $A\cup B$. Fpr any $k$ with $1\le k\le n$, we have three choices as to where $k$ will go, $A$, $B$, or $C$. So there are $3^n$ ways to partition $S$ into $3$ parts labelled A, B, C.

Comment: This is analogous to the calculation of the number of subsets of $S$. In that case we are dividing $S$ into $2$ parts $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is the subset we are producing, and $B$ is the complement. For every $k$ there are $2$ choices as to where $k$ will go, $A$ (the set we want) or $B$. Thus $S$ has $2^n$ subsets.